# biblatex-chicago: How do I make use of "supranotes"?

Tags: biblatex-chicago, legal-style

Like the title says. I have `supranotes=true` in the options for the package. I have two footnotes (made with `\footcite{}`) with another footnote in between so I don't just get "ibid". But still the footnote is printed with the usual information, no "*supra*". The [biblatex-chicago manual](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf) says "you’ll only see it in certain sorts of citation, automatically controlled by biblatex-chicago in accordance with the Bluebook specification". What kind of citations are these?

Comment: Which style do you use? `notes` or `authordate`?

Comment: @moewe, as far as I could gr[e|as]p both styles use the supra facilities, but in not precisely identical ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the sources of `biblatex-chicago` we find `supra` related content in the bibmacros `cite:short:legislation`, `cite:short:legal` and `cite:shorthand:legal` which are applied to their respective entrytypes: `legislation` and `legal`.

Comment: That makes sense since the Bluebook is a style guide for legal citations and the CMS defers to the Bluebook when it comes to citations of case law and legislations.

Comment: Oh, I see. I only tried for the `@book` and `@article` bibliography entry types so that's why it doesn't work. But I think it's correct to use *supra* for anything. I've seen other authors in law use it for articles for example. Do you know if I can expand it to work for other entry types?

Comment: @user.S What is "correct" or "incorrect" is a matter of standard, and `biblatex-chicago` tries to follow the Chicago Manual of Style.